# Is there a way to limit TeamCity REST API 'changes' output to specific branch?

Tags: teamcity

I query for changes occurred since some VCS commit:

`https://teamcity.mycompany.com/app/rest/changes?locator=buildType:(id:myCfgId),sinceChange(version:mySHA)&fields=change(*)`

This returns all the changes made to all tracked branches since the moment when `mySHA` is committed. How can I restrict/filter the results to certain branch? [ChangeLocator](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/changelocator.html) argument itself does not deal with branches.